# Two Step Left Join In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to left join two tables. Table 1 (tb1) is like:

```
DATE_         ID           NAME
2007-09       1            Apple
2007-10       2            Pear
2007-11       3            Banana
2007-12       null         Cherry
2008-01       11           Kiwi
  ...         ...           ...
```

And Table 2 (tb2) is like:

```
 DATE_         ID           NAME      Sales
2007-09       1            Apple       200
2007-10       2            Pear        100
2007-11       3            Banana      300
2007-12       4            Cherry      500
  ...         ...           ...        ...
```

I want to first left join two tables using `ID` first. For the records in Table 2 where `ID` is null I want to use `name` as the key.

I know I can first left join Table 1 on `tb1.ID = tb2.ID` and `tb1.DATE_ = tb2.DATE`, 
 using the method `create table my_table select as` creating a new table, and then do the left join again for the new table. The problem is I have thousands of records in table 1 and 2. Even when I tried to create a new table for the first join using the `ID`, SQL Workbench gives me an error code saying connection lost.

`create view my_view` would solve the connection problem. But I wonder how can I do the two step join with a view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date
   AND (t1.id = t2.id OR (t1.id IS NULL AND t1.name = t2.name));
```

Sample output:

```
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+-------+
| DATE       | ID   | NAME   | DATE       | ID   | NAME   | Sales |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+-------+
| 2007-09-01 | 1    | Apple  | 2007-09-01 |    1 | Apple  |   200 |
| 2007-10-01 | 2    | Pear   | 2007-10-01 |    2 | Pear   |   100 |
| 2007-11-01 | 3    | Banana | 2007-11-01 |    3 | Banana |   300 |
| 2007-12-01 | NULL | Cherry | 2007-12-01 |    4 | Cherry |   500 |
| 2008-01-01 | 11   | Kiwi   | NULL       | NULL | NULL   |  NULL |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+-------+
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=957f3aa3784f5bb3538e4447f76ab83d) demo

Comment: @Strawberry Care to explain?

Comment: No - my mistake.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.